# Reponse link is lost when responding to a message in chat with an image

Tags: bug, chat

I noticed this yesterday, but perhaps it has been occurring for longer. When I used to respond to a message in chat with an uploaded image, it would properly link my one-boxed image back to the message I was responding to. Now, however, when I hit the button to reply to a message and then upload an image, it posts the image and chops out the :number portion that identifies it as a response to a previous message. I then have to go edit the response id back in manually.

I'm assuming this is a bug rather than an intentional change in behavior.

**The steps to reproduce are:**

1. Hit the "Reply" button to a message in chat. As usual, the chatbox will automatically fill in something like below.
   [image]
2. Hit the upload button. Select a file for upload.
3. The posted message will no longer be response to the previous message as it used to be (in other words, the :15389654 will be gone). You can edit it back in manually and it works fine.

Comment: It actually never did this and you're crazy.

Comment: It bothers me that I distinctly remember this working in the past when apparently it never actually worked in the past. I AM NOT GOING INSANE.

Comment: Whew, okay, sanity restored. I probably used to have the userscript installed that "fixed" this.